# PHP on IIS setting up a Production and Development Environment

Tags: php, iis

At work I have a couple of Windows Server 2008's that I've installed PHP on.   That's working well.

I've been trying to find information on creating a production and development side on the same server.  Maybe I'm not searching on good keywords.   Is there perhaps a good guide out there for PHP on IIS where there are separate running development and production environments matched up to different sets of 'wwww' folders on the servers?

Answer (score -1):

In IIS you can create multiple website, just create a DEV and a Production website with a set of different folders as you suggested.

PHP is irrelevant, this works with all sites no matter what they are coded in under IIS.

I don't think you'll find a guide, because best practice isn't to run production and dev on the same machine.  But you'll find a guide on how to create multiple websites in IIS.